# What does tsconfig.json's references.path.prepend do?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I don't understand the official documentation of what [prepend](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#prepend-with-outfile) does, even though I understand everything up to this point:

[image]

The second paragraph is what confuses me.

> Prepending a project will include the project’s output above the output of the current project. All output files (.js, .d.ts, .js.map, .d.ts.map) will be emitted correctly.

1. I don't understand these two sentences *at all*. Can someone word them in a different way?
2. I'd like to see an example showing the difference between `prepend: true` vs `prepend: false` / `undefined`.
3. <del>I'd like to see an example showing the difference between `prepend: true` with `outFile` set vs unset.</del> It's an error to use prepend *without* `outFile` set.

---

### Partial answer:

Based on my discovery re: #3, I've deduced what `prepend` does  (probably).

```
./
  foo/
    tsconfig.json
  bar/
    tsconfig.json
```

If foo's tsconfig.json references `../bar` with `prepend: true`, then `../bar`'s `outFile` will be *prepended* to foo's `outFile`.

Not sure what'll happen if prepend is off in the same scenario. I assume there'll be two output files, but I don't know how the load order would be determined.

Comment: I agree that the phrasing is cryptic and ambiguous at best due to the repeated noun usage ("project") without disambiguating modifiers. Did you experiment with this setting before posting this question? Also see: [`outFile`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outFile)

Comment: @jsejcksn I haven't experimented yet because I don't know enough about `references` to know if I've set it up the right way. A lot of times, it's hard to know where to see the effect the tsconfig change you made. I checked out `outFile`'s docs before posting. *That* section is easy for me to understand, but I don't understand how it relates to `prepend`.  Thanks!

Comment: @jsejcksn there are also other parts of tsconfig (even in this section of the docs, in fact) that change other settings without telling you. e.g., `tsc -b effectively acts as if noEmitOnError is enabled for all projects.`